# Appropriate way to throw an error in if-else block

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I would like to know, which one (A or B) is the appropriate way of code writing for throw statement in if-else block:

The below block is for illustration purpose and assuming things are defined

//A

```
if(ruleId !=100)
      throw new RuleError(RULES_EXCEEDED);
const getRuleList = getRules(rule);
// Some more code down the line.....
```

//B

```
if(ruleId !=100)
      throw new RuleError(RULES_EXCEEDED);
else {
 const getRuleList = getRules(rule);
 // Some more code down the line.....
}
```

The only difference in B is an explicit use of else statement. My question is here, what is the best way to write. (This is an nodejs example but the theory will be applicable to other languages well)

Comment: Completely up to you, it's only a style choice

Comment: I prefer first approach because it validates all `false` behavior at the top and the main logic is written cleanly after that, no nested code in `else` statement. But as **CertainPerformance** said, its totally up to you what you choose.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance and Shaharya. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: The whole purpose behind this question is to check the general pattern & acceptance, while writing such if-else .. throw code in any programming language. Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using block A, especially if you have nested if/else blocks.

A is also called guard clause and is useful, if you don't want to execute a whole method in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Appreciate your comments

Comment: Please flag opinion-based questions for closure once you have the ability to flag. If you don't have the ability to flag, please just avoid posting answers to such questions